# Error: value.split is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to code a custom filter in AngularJS.This filter will capitalize a text. On executing the code, this error has been thrown "**Error: value.split is not a function**"

File "filter.js" :

```
"use strict";
    angular.module("MyApp", []);
    angular.module("MyApp").controller("UserController", ["$scope", function($scope)
    {
        this.infos = 
        {
            firstname: "David",
            lastname: "Michel",
            cellphone: 123456
        };
    }]);

    angular.module('MyApp').filter('capitalize', function()
    {
        return function(value){
            var result = null;
            var words = value.split(' ');
            words.forEach(function(item){
                if (result){
                    result += ' ';
                }else{
                    result = '';
                }
                result += item.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + item.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            });
            return result;
        };
    });
```

File "filter.html" :

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="filter.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="UserController as user">        
            Firstname : {{user.infos.firstname | capitalize }}
            Lastname : {{user.infos.lastname | capitalize }}
            Cellphone : {{user.infos.cellphone | capitalize }}      
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could we see how are you implementing the filter in the HTML?

Comment: @NathanBeck I've just updated my question : File "filter.html"

Comment: @NathanBeck that works var words = value.toString().split(' ');

Comment: `{{ user.infos.cellphone | capitalize }}` may be the issue. `infos.cellphone` is an `int` which has no `split()` method. `value.toString().split(' ')` works as you've converted it to a string

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you've got a function parameter named `value` which hides the outer variable, `value`.

Try to declare your value as a variable like this :

```
 angular.module('MyApp').filter('capitalize', function()
{
    return function(){
        var value = 'something';
        var result = null;
        var words = value.split(' ');
        words.forEach(function(item){
            if (result){
                result += ' ';
            }else{
                result = '';
            }
            result += item.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + item.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        });
        return result;
    };
```

Comment: The parameter `value` within `return function(value)` is the string angular hands over to the filter. Setting this as a static value (in your example, 'something') would defeat the purpose of the filter, as you will always return the capitalized word `Something`.